# how to populate complex array of list of array structure c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I`m getting hard time of trying to populate that structure:

```
var arrlist = new List<int[]>()[length];
```

What I want: an array of fixed length of lists.
Each list would contain unknown number of arrays of length 2.

trying to add following list into above array:

```
var digfaclist = new List<int[]>();
var factors = new int[2] {i, j};
digfaclist.Add(factors);
```

I am looping through arrlist and populating it with length 2 arrays in lists. After that I am trying to do smth like:

```
arrlist[0] = digfaclist;
```

is it even viable or I should go with some other approach? performance/structure-vice.

Comment: Why don't you use an ArrayList? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Odrai Because as a type it is effectively obsolete; one should basically always use `List` instead.

Comment: We can't know if this is viable to you.  If it's working for you, then it's working for you.  If it's not, you're going to have to explain what about it isn't working, specifically.

Comment: Indeed. Admittedly it's simpler to use a collection initializer: `var factorList = new List<int[]> { new[] { i, j } };` but what you've got should work too - aside from the `arrlist` declaration, which has a stray `()`.

Comment: Why not use a Struct instead of an array of two ints ? if there is always two ints ...

Comment: @Sharped An array is mutable, a `struct` shouldn't be, so either this object is never mutated, or he'd be using a mutable struct when he shouldn't be.  That, and it doesn't represent a logical value (it represents two values).  It's far more likely that a `class` would be correct, not a `struct`.

Comment: So a class of two ints if mutability is a concern ....

Comment: It is really unclear what problem you're trying to solve. You have an array of lists of arrays? at some point you might want to consider classes to make the maintenance of these objects more manageable.

Comment: Thank you Jon Skeet actully I overlooked () and that was a reason.

Comment: Thank you Rufus, I am just a beginner with c# and will try to implement classes here.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
int count = 15;


List<int[]>[] list = new List<int[]>[count];


for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    list[i] = new List<int[]>(); //you have to initialize them
}
list[0].Add(new []{30, 22});
list[0].Add(new []{11, 22});
foreach (int[] numbers in list[0])
{
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",numbers)); //test
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var arr = new int[][] {
  new int[] { 1, 2 },
  new int[] { 3 ,4 },
  new int[] { 5, 6 } }
var arrlist = arr.ToList();
```

Remember internally a list still maintains an array of items.

Comment: He wants an array of lists of arrays of ints, not a list of arrays of arrays of ints.

Comment: but list can be of not-fixed size, and I need it as i dont know number of arrays that i need to add to list.

Comment: I wouldnt recommend going to a jagged array of rank 3 or more. If `int[][][]` is needed then its time to reconsider the approach.